# Azure Webjob supports Async execution if yes how?

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I want to execute my `Azure Webjob` methods `async` but I wonder `Azure Webjob` supports `Async Execution or not`

Can anyone help me in this. to execute `webjob` methods `ProcessSub1Messages` and `ProcessSub2Messages` asynchronously.

```
namespace WebJob1
{
public class Functions 
{
      public static void ProcessSub1Messages([ServiceBusTrigger("TestTopic", "Sub1")] BrokeredMessage message,
        TextWriter logger)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Webjob Start for Sub1 {0} {1}", message.MessageId, DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(100000);
            Console.WriteLine("Webjob End for Sub1 {0} {1}", message.MessageId, DateTime.Now);
        }

        public static void ProcessSub2Messages([ServiceBusTrigger("TestTopic", "Sub2")] BrokeredMessage message,
        TextWriter logger)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Webjob Start for Sub2 {0} {1}", message.MessageId, DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(100000);
            Console.WriteLine("Webjob End for Sub2 {0} {1}", message.MessageId, DateTime.Now);
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the WebJobs SDK supports async. Just change the return type of the function from void to `Task`:

```
 public static async Task ProcessSub2Messages(
    [ServiceBusTrigge(("TestTopic", "Sub2")] BrokeredMessage message,
    TextWriter logger)
    {
        // async operations here
    }
```

Comment: hey thanks for the confirmation I guess support is added in newer version. what about `await` in above code ?

Comment: What do you mean by "what about `await` in the above code"?